# How to return static class

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to return a static class from a method. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Below is my code:

```
class Dimension {
      static class Sides {
          int i, j
    }


    Sides findInGrid() {
       // Here I want to set i and j to values of x and y
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend your method to return `Sides` rather than `Position`? What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: wouldn't returning the static class be "return Dimension.Sides.class;"?

Comment: I think what you want is to return an instance of type `Sides` with instance fields `i` and `j` set to whatever you require. Careful with the jargon.

Comment: In groovy and java it should be "class" not "Class".

Comment: @mszalbach : Sorry about that.. I have edited my question.And yes I want to return an instance of type sides with instance fields i and j set to x and y.

Comment: So use the `new` keyword to instantiate an Object of type `Sides`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am not understanding your problem but you can easily use a Static class like this with the new keyword.

Simple implementation:

```
class Dimension {
    static class Sides {
        int i, j
    }


   Sides findInGrid() {
       return new Sides(i: 3, j: 4)
   }
}
```

You can use this from an other class via:

```
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension()
    Dimension.Sides side = dimension.findInGrid();
```

And since its a static class you can also create Sides instances without having a Dimension instance. So you can use below code in other classes too.

```
new Dimension.Sides( i: 6, j: 7)
```